# A random number generator that can get different numbers in < a second

Tags: c++, random

I'm in need of a C++ (pseudo, i don't care) random number generator that can get me different numbers every time I call the function. This could be simply the way I seed it, maybe there's a better method, but every random generator I've got doesn't generate a new number every time it's called. I've got a need to get several random numbers per second on occasion, and any RNG i plug in tends to get the same number several times in a row. 
Of course, I know why, because it's seeded by the second, so it only generates a new number every second, but I need to, somehow, get a new number on every call. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Sounds like you do it like this:

```
int get_rand() {
    srand(time(0));
    return rand();
}
```

Which would explain why you get the same number within one second. But you have to do it like this:

```
int get_rand() {
    return rand();
}
```

And call srand *once* at program startup.

Comment: litb, what would I do without you! Thanks a lot, I had a feeling it was another 'shouldda known better' programmer-inflicted error!

Answer (score 7):

You only need to seed the generator once with `srand()` when you start, after that just call the `rand()` function. If you seed the generator twice with the same seed, you'll get the same value back each time.

Answer (score 4):

You should only seed the PRNG **once**.

Answer (score 3):

[Boost.Random](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/random/index.html) has a variety of pretty good random number generators.

Answer (score 1):

If you're generating a large number of random numbers, you could try an XORShift generator. For longs (8 bit):

```
// initial setup
unsigned long x = ... init from time etc ...
// each time we want a random number in 'x':
x ^= x << 21;
x ^= x >> 35;
x ^= x << 4;
```

Answer (score 0):

This code generates a  unique random number only once.

```
#include <ctime>
# include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main()
{

      int size=100;
      int random_once[100];
      srand(time(0));

      for (int i=0;i<size;i++)  // generate unique random number only once
      {
          random_once[i]=rand() % size;
          for(int j=0;j<i;j++) if (random_once[j]==random_once[i]) i--;   
      }

      for ( i=0;i<size;i++) cout<<" "<<random_once[i]<<"\t";

  return 0;
```